# How to define custom controlled unitaries in OPENQASM 2.0?

Tags: programming, ibm-q-experience, qasm

According to the [OPENQASM 2.0](https://arxiv.org/abs/1707.03429) documentation, it's possible to define custom unitary gates using the format:

```
gate name(params) qargs
{
body
}
```

where the optional parameter list `params` is a comma-separated list of variable parameter names, and the argument list `qargs` is a comma-separated list of qubit arguments.

In my specific case, I'm trying to implement a single-qubit **controlled** unitary which will act on two qubits. So is there a way to define a custom controlled unitary gate in OPENQASM 2.0? It should work on the new [IBM Quantum Experience Beta](https://quantum-computing.ibm.com/).

Comment: How if given your unitary? As a matrix? A sequence of quantum gates? A quantum gate previously defined with the syntax you gave above?

Comment: @Nelimee As a sequence of quantum gates acting on two qubits. I can write the two-qubit unitary in the syntax above I suppose, but I'm not sure how to implement the control by a third qubit.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, I'm pretty sure that the functionality you desire does not exist. You'll need to do it by constructing the unitary yourself, for example via [this method](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/1344/given-a-decomposition-for-a-unitary-u-how-do-you-decompose-the-corresponding?rq=1) provided in the answer to another question.

For reference, the full specification for OpenQASM 2.0 can be found [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1707.03429).