# How to implement controlled u3 gate from Qiskit using simpler gates?

Tags: quantum-gate, gate-synthesis, universal-gates

I am trying to implement the u3 controlled gate (able to rotate the qubit in any specified direction in 3 dimensions if the control is 1, for two qubits) using simpler gates. The simpler gates available are:

X(), Y(), Z(), H(), K(), T() Single-qubit gates.

rot_X(step), rot_Y(step), rot_Z(step) Single-qubit rotations with the angle (step⋅2π256)

CNOT(q), CPHASE(q) Two-qubit gates with q (qubit) as target.

Comment: See the answer by @glS at https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/1344/given-a-decomposition-for-a-unitary-u-how-do-you-decompose-the-corresponding

Comment: Hi @AHusain! in U=eiαAXBXC, what should be the value of α? Since the three input parameters defines only the gates A,B,C and not α hence α is under-defined here?